# Fill data from an api to an Array With VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

need to fill an array with data that I consult from an api

this is my queried array

```
getUsers() {
        this.$http.get("users").then(res => {
        this.users = res.data.data;
          });
  }
  }
```

This returns my request

[image]

I want to fill another array according to the data of my request, I am trying it this way

```
getUsers() {
        this.$http.get("users").then(res => {
          this.users = res.data.data;
          for(var i = 0; i <= this.users.length; i++) {
              this.user[i].id = this.tableData[i].id
          }
          });
  }
  },
```

This returns my function

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWLcg.png]

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: need to fill an array with data that I consult from an api

Comment: u are doing it reverse.  do it like this.tableData[i].id = this.user[i].id 

or best way to copy over the array would be using spread operator
this.tableData = {...res.data.data}

Comment: that's how it worked for me Thanks this.tableData = {...res.data.data}

Comment: nice! you can close the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's how it worked for me Thanks this.tableData = {...res.data.data}